# How to prove that a field is a vector space on R

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider a field F. Verify that the field W is a vector space on F. We let F denote either the set of real numbers or the set of complex numbers

a)$W = F[x] = \{p(x) = a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n:a_i \in F\} $

I know that to proof that I need to use the axioms of a vector space, but I do not understand those notations, I would appreciate help so I could understand it.

Comment: so a 3-in-1 question ?

Comment: Basically it is, but I just need 1 to understand the others!

Comment: Then please edit and be more precise .

Comment: Done! Could I see the solution on that one?

Comment: Now, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be asking about the notation:

$F[x]$ is the so-called space of *polynomials* in one variable over $F$. Three examples of elements of $F[x]$ (for $F=\Bbb Q$ or something similarly familiar) are $$1\\x^2-1\\5x^{17}+3x^9-2x^5$$
while things like
$$
\frac1x\\
5\sqrt{x}-4\\
3^x-2^x
$$
are not polynomials and therefore not part of our $W$.

The coefficients of these polynomials are all elements in $F$, and the rule for adding polynomials and for scaling a polynomial by a constant are exactly the way you're used to when dealing with polynomials.

Comment: And maybe some examples of expressions that *aren’t* polynomials, might be in order: $3-5\sqrt x$, (3-x)/(x^2+x+1)$, etc. Anyhow, I gave you a plus one.

Answer (score 1):

*What does $W=F[x]=\{p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n\mid a_i\in F\}$ mean?*

$W$ is a set of polynomials, of degree $n$ or less (not sure if $n$ is fixed or not), whose coefficients are from $F$. Let's look at a particular case with $n=2$ and $F=\Bbb R$. Then we're looking at $$W=\Bbb R[x]=\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2\mid a_i\in\Bbb R\}$$

For instance all of $2x+4,\pi+\frac{2}{3}x-x^2, 1$ are inside $W$. Because they are polynomials of degree $2$ or less, and all the coefficents are in $\Bbb R$.

*Is $W$ a vector space?*

To find out, we need to first find out what the vectors themself are. Vectors should be elements of $W$, so te vectors should be the polynomials. To convince you of this you can write the polynomial $\mathbf{f}=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$ as $\mathbf{f}=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

Now you only need to check the axioms of a vector space, and how you define addition and scalar multiplication:

Given $\mathbf{f},\mathbf{g},\mathbf{h}\in W$ and scalars $a,b\in\Bbb R$:

- $\mathbf{f}+(\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{h})=(\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{g})+\mathbf{h}$, this is often immidiate
- $\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{g}=\mathbf{g}+\mathbf{f}$, this is also often immidiate
- There is a zero vector, $\mathbf{0}$, such that  $\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{f}$ for every $\mathbf{f}\in W$
- $a(b\mathbf{f})=(ab)\mathbf{f}$
- $1\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{f}$
- $a(\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{g})=a\mathbf{f}+a\mathbf{g}$
- $(a+b)\mathbf{f}=a\mathbf{f}+b\mathbf{f}$